# Why is Tesseract returning the wrong number here?

Tags: python, ocr, tesseract

I'm using Tesseract to scan dates that have been cropped out of an image. A date will look e.g. like this:

[image: date to be scanned with Tesseract]

For almost all dates this works perfectly fine, no problem at all. However, sometimes it trips up in a strange manner, usually involving 3s and 5s. In the case above, it sees the last 6 numbers as `0435000`, which needless to say is 7 numbers, a 5 has been added in out of nowhere (as suspected, right after a 3). Another common mistake is interpreting "2300" as `3500`. As far as I can remember it's always been only the last portion (the hours and minutes) that trips it up, never the first part of the date (I've been running it a lot of times daily for several months). Does anyone know what is causing this? And also perhaps what I can do to make it more consistent?

For what it's worth I'm not running Tesseract with any special commands, just `tesseract date.jpg date`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Image quality is very important and you should use rgb b&w:

```
import subprocess
import cv2
import pytesseract

# Image manipulation
# Commands https://imagemagick.org/script/convert.php
mag_img = r'D:\Programme\ImageMagic\magick.exe'
con_bw = r"D:\Programme\ImageMagic\convert.exe" 

in_file = r'Qkqxn.jpg'
out_file = r'Qkqxn_inv.jpg'

# Play with black and white and contrast for better results
process = subprocess.run([con_bw, in_file, "-resize", "70%","-threshold","35%", out_file])

# Text ptocessing
pytesseract.pytesseract.tesseract_cmd=r'C:\Program Files\Tesseract-OCR\tesseract.exe'
img = cv2.imread(out_file)

# Parameters see tesseract doc 
custom_config = r'--psm 7 --oem 3 -c tessedit_char_whitelist=_01234567890' 

tex = pytesseract.image_to_string(img, config=custom_config)
print(tex)

with open("numbers.txt", 'w') as f:
    f.writelines(tex)

cv2.imshow('image',img)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Output:
[image]

Comment: Thanks, resizing and using a threshold with convert seems to be the "magick" step (heh), and seems to be solving the troublesome test cases I've aggregated. I'll let it run for 24 hours and make sure it gets everything correctly, and then I'll mark this as solved if it all goes fine.

Comment: Let me know the result.

Comment: There's only half an hour left of dates now, but it's already passed all the troublesome ones from previously, so I can quite safely mark this as solved now. I ended up resizing to 50% and using a threshold of just 5%, in case anyone else might be interested; that seemed to work best in making some nice and wide numbers that could easily be read. Also perhaps worth mentioning is that I didn't use the Python script above, since I was already using different bash commands to run the tasks, so I rather added the convert commands to the convert command I was already running to make the date.